# Put MSE under Stack Exchange in the Top Bar, when Stack Exchange is the current community

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, top-bar, stack-exchange-button

On regular sites, the current community you're on lists its meta directly under it in the new Multicollider. The big exception is that there's no meta listed when you're in SE chat and not under a site, or when you're on the Stack Exchange homepage, or the full hot questions list, or anywhere else where the generic "Stack Exchange" entry pops up as the current site. Up until yesterday, there wasn't anything to list there.

[image: Poor sad Stack Exchange without its Meta]

But now, Stack Exchange has a Meta to list there! So, let's get it up. Yes, there's already a "meta" link in the top bar on most of those places, and I personally have MSE as a favorite site anyway, but it feels quite inconsistent not to have the meta listed right there where I always look to get to the meta of the site I'm currently on.

Comment: That's because Meta Stack Exchange is not a regular per-site Meta. And Stack Exchange is not a regular Q&A site either.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Well, yes, I know that's why it's not there yet. But it still feels like it belongs there. If nothing else, it's very much the correct Meta to head to for issues related to any of those pages.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Well, the first part was the case with MSO as well, which *did* show up in the correct place.

Comment: @FEichinger: True enough.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An excellent idea. :)

This will go live later today, along with the inverse - stackexchange.com will be linked in the site switcher when MSE is the current community.